# NAN String on Maxent

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, string, maxent

I'm using NDVI for one of my environmental layers, i got it from google earth engine and process the data using ArcGis Desktop. I already convert it to ascii and check there's some NAN in my data. What should i do? Am i allowed to change the NAN into -9999 ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think that it would cause any harm setting NaN (Not a Number) to your NoData value, either way the cell couldn't be used for processing as it doesn't have a valid value.

Comment: i did it, it worked thank you so much!